# In Preview App (PDF) why is text entering in some fields but others it won't?

Tags: imac, pdf, preview

I am trying to enter text in PDFs with the Preview app. Ins some fields the text enters, no problem. In others I get the text enter box but when I type nothing happens. Why is this? I can put text there by using Markup and creating my own text box but it is tedious. I would like to enter right into the box.[image: Here I was able to enter the date but not on the line below]

Comment: Are you sure the fields in question are actually fields you are supposed to be able to edit (either because the author didn't want you to edit those fields or because the PDF wasn't designed properly)?

Comment: No...I am not sure...but...I AM THE AUTHOR, so how can I fix that?

Comment: Oh, in that case you would need to edit your question to clarify _how_ you designed the PDF (what software, version, the process you're using, etc) and then we should be able to help you.